# Add HTML element with CSS to plotly line chart in R

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

How can I add a vertical y-axis scroll bar in a plotly line chart?

```
    library(plotly)
    
    x <- c(1:100)
    random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
    data <- data.frame(x, random_y)
    
    p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

    p
```

I have a html code for scroll bar but i don't know how to integrate that code with plot

```
   Html <div style="overflow-y:scroll;height: 200px;">
```

Comment: I suggest adding a scroll bar with Plotly instead of html.

Comment: i have tried but for y axis i didnt find any documentation to add a scroll bar in R @Hamzah

Comment: You can integrate both by using shiny

Comment: See this example between python and Dash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286541/how-to-create-a-vertical-scroll-bar-with-plotly You can do it between R and Shiny

Comment: Also see this if it can help https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/yaxis/inverted-bar-scrollbar/

Comment: p%>%layout(xaxis = list(rangeslider = list())) using this code i can add slide in x axis i have tried same for y axis its not working

Comment: i am not aware of shiny but i will take a look@Hamzah

Comment: Rangeslider is dedicated only for x-axis as written in the documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the library `htmltools`. You can use HTML exactly as you've written it.

```
library(plotly)
library(htmltools)

x <- c(1:100)
random_y <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
data <- data.frame(x, random_y)

p <- plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~random_y, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')

p

# this combines the plot and your y scroll
browsable(div(style = "overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px;", p))
```